# In the first else statement of the function, what exactly is the purpose of making a property equal a value?

Tags: javascript, json

Why is [value] in brackets in the first else statement but then not in brackets in the second else if statement? Also how can a prop be made to equal a value and what purpose does that serve?

This is the code:

```
// Setup
var collection = {
    "2548": {
      "album": "Slippery When Wet",
      "artist": "Bon Jovi",
      "tracks": [ 
        "Let It Rock", 
        "You Give Love a Bad Name" 
      ]
    },
    "2468": {
      "album": "1999",
      "artist": "Prince",
      "tracks": [ 
        "1999", 
        "Little Red Corvette" 
      ]
    },
    "1245": {
      "artist": "Robert Palmer",
      "tracks": [ ]
    },
    "5439": {
      "album": "ABBA Gold"
    }
};
// Keep a copy of the collection for tests
var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));

// Only change code below this line
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {
   if(collection[id][prop]) {
    collection[id][prop].push(value);
   }
   else {
    collection[id][prop]=[value];
   }
  } else if (value !== "") {
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  } else {
    delete collection[id][prop];
  }

  return collection;
}

// Alter values below to test your code
updateRecords(5439, "tracks", "Take a Chance on Me");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {
  if(collection[id][prop]) {
   collection[id][prop].push(value);
 }
 else {
  collection[id][prop]=[value];
 }
} else if (value !== "") {
  collection[id][prop] = value;
} else {
  delete collection[id][prop];
}
```

If I translate the above code into pseudo code, it would be

If the property is "tracks and the value entered is not empty =>

[
  If the collection object already has that property, push the new value into   the array.
  Else, ie, if the collection object does not have that property present, then  create a new array with value as the only element in the array and assign that array to the property. 
]

Else (this would mean prop is not equal to "tracks") =>
[
assign the value to property
]

else if value is null =>
[
delete the property from collection object
]

In short, the logic is,
If the new prop is "tracks", either create a new array or add to the existing array of values stored against "tracks". 
If not, and if value is not empty, assign that value to the property
If value is empty, delete the property itself.

Comment: Are the last two else statements you simplified in the correct order?

Isn't "else if value is null =>" the second to last, not last else?

Comment: Based on your code, they are. 

Removal of the property happens at last if the value that is passed in is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
collection[id][prop]=[value];
```

means that the data looks like this

```
var collection = {
id: {
prop:
[value]
}
}
```

Whereas without the brackets it looks like this

```
  var collection = {
    id: {
    prop:
    value
    }
    }
```

So in the case of having brackets, we're saying that prop is equal to an array with one element inside, value.

In the other case it's assigning value without an array.

As far as why this is being done in this way? Not sure.

Comment: If there is an array already, it appends to the existing array. Otherwise it creates one.